# Limit email count which is getting fired by alertmanager

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

Can someone provide some suggestions on limiting the email alerting count to send only one email instead of 100 duplicate emails when a particular metric condition is triggered and alert starts to fire. Any alertmanager config to make it fire only one email instead of many duplicate emails? Any pointers will be really helpful please

Comment: First, this being configuration question, doesn't belong to SO. Consider moving to [su].

Comment: Also, need to provide more information on the problem. What rule(s) cause a problem? How is you alertmanager configured? Do you use alert grouping, and if yes - how?

Comment: I'd ask system-administration questions like this on [sf] or [devops.se], not necessarily Super User.

Comment: @markalex but this is a k8s config question right? Does it not belong here?

Comment: @Mahesh, no, it does not: please read the description of kubernetes tag. Depending on your situation you indeed might need to use one of sites David mentioned.

Comment: These questions are sometimes still answered here, if the one who stumbled across them knows enough and doesn't care about topicness. But it's simply easier to find expert on matters of configuration there, rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/alerting.md), you can refer on the following YAML file to setup interval time to send notification alert:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: alertmanager-sample-config
  labels:
    alertmanagerConfig: alertmanager-config
spec:
  route:
    groupBy: ['job']
    groupWait: 30s
    groupInterval: 5m
    repeatInterval: 12h
    receiver: 'webhook'
  receivers:
  - name: 'webhook'
    webhookConfigs:
    - url: 'http://web-hook-link.com/'
```

You may refer to the official prometheus [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route) to further understand Alertmanager configuration file.